# Passing data between pages Xamarin Shell navigation

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I have a Xamarin forms app with a form split across multiple pages, I want to pass the object data to the next or previous page. I am navigating using the Xamarin Shell. What method or setup can I use to achieve this?

The options I am aware of and my perceived issues with them:

- JSON string the object and pass it as a parameter.

This seems incorrect as the data is being converted back and forth.

- Pass every property of the object as an individual parameter.

Massively long winded with many properties and inflexible to change.

- Store the data to a SQLite database.

I would not want to store an incomplete record in the table and using the current SQLiteAsyncConnection, I don't believe I can have 2 tables created from the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,you can pass data using query property attributes .

Navigation data can be received by decorating the receiving class with a QueryPropertyAttribute for each query parameter.

For more, check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes .

**In addition**,another method is to create a global varible in your app, them you can access this varible in your app.

For example:

1.create class `MyVariables.cs`and add static variable for your model (e.g. `MyViewModel` ) :

```
public  class MyVariables
{
    public static MyViewModel myViewModel { get; set; } = new MyViewModel { Name = "test1" };
}
```

`MyViewModel.cs`

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.You can modify or access your variable in your app:

```
 // modify the variable
 MyVariables.myViewModel.Name = "test2022";

// access the variable
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("the data is: " + MyVariables.myViewModel.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we could only pass simple data now. And this feature will be added in the future: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6848 You can create multiple QueryPropertyAttribute to access different data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data Another approach is to convert the object to a JSON string like:

var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
Then pass it when navigating.